# Redirect to Android App from a Website?

Tags: javascript, android, html, redirect

When a user opens a website I want one of the following two cases to be happen:

1. If the app mycoolapp is installed redirect the user to the app using the custom url scheme mycoolapp://
2. If the app is not installed stay on the current page without posting or redirecting to an unknown page or an error popup.

Case 1 is easy you can use the following code:

```
window.location = "mycoolapp://";
```

This will work if the app is installed on the device. When the app is not installed it redirects the user to a blank page which is unknown.

For case 2 I have a solution using an iFrame which works great on iOS and on the native Android browser. It does not work on Chrome for Android.

```
var redirect = function (location) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('src', location);
    iframe.setAttribute('width', '1px');
    iframe.setAttribute('height', '1px');
    iframe.setAttribute('position', 'absolute');
    iframe.setAttribute('top', '0');
    iframe.setAttribute('left', '0');
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
};    

redirect('mycoolapp://');
```

When the app is installed it is working on the native Android browser, but on Chrome for Android there is not redirect. Nothing happens on the page.

**How can I make redirect to my app working on Chrome for Android without redirecting to a blank page when the app is not installed?**

**Edit:** I know that you can use an Intent

```
window.location = "intent://#Intent;package=com.mycoolapp;scheme=mycoolapp;launchFlags=268435456;end;";
```

This is not what I want because it launches the app page on google play if the app is not installed. Is there a way that it will not redirect to google play?

Comment: on android do not use "special" scheme ... use http scheme in Intent filter ... the browser will ask user to finish the action with browser or with your app(if installed)

Comment: @Selvin Could you please post an answer for your idea?

Comment: it is the same as RGraham's answer

Answer (score 11):

```
 Add this in manifest file,note the scheme.

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="startci" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

in html give the code, the scheme is same as in the manifest file.

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;scheme=startci;package=gramener.star;end">click here</a>
```

if you want to add parameter to your app use this

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;scheme=startci://open?url_param=hi santhosh;package=gramener.star;end">click here</a>
```

if the app is not installed so if you want to redirect to some other page add the fallback url like this. the url must be encoded

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;scheme=startci://open?url_param=hi santhosh;package=gramener.star;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fzxing.org;end">click here</a>
```

to get the parameter add below code

```
 Uri data = this.getIntent().getData();
    if (data != null && data.isHierarchical()) {
        if (data.getQueryParameter("url_param") != null) {
            String param = data.getQueryParameter("url_param");               
            Log.d("the param is",param);
              //do something here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't *need* to launch your app on a custom protocol. It will work for *any* address, e.g. in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="www.mycoolapp.com" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/Android" />
</intent-filter>
```

This means you can direct the user using:

```
window.location = "/Android";
```

If the app is installed, Android will prompt to "Open With". If not, the user will just be taken to the /Android page in their browser.

Comment: I use custom url because I use the same url scheme for iOs this makes things much more easy.

Comment: @confile Do a quick browser-sniff. Use what you have for iOS and the above for Android.

Comment: if the app is not installed window.location = "/Android"; will open a blank page in the browser. This is not what I want. If the app is not installed the user should stay at the current page.