# redirect to app from custom tabs

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am creating android app in react native. my app is on local system not uploaded on live server. I have used CustomTabs to open external url . I want to redirect back from external url to app .I have made changes into AndroidManifest.xml:-

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="mywebsite.com"
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:path="/index">
                </data>
        </intent-filter>
```

and added this on my external url:

```
<a href="intent://mywebsite.com/index#Intent;package=com.myapp;scheme=http;end;"/>click</a>
```

when i clicked its redirecting to play store. I want its redirecting to the my app i.e on my local system. how can i add url because app is on local system. is there any way to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these parameters in the intent filter:

```
<data android:pathPattern="/Android" />
```

This means you can direct the user using:

```
window.location = "/Android";
```

This should work for you, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643272/redirect-to-android-app-from-a-website) also

Comment: I have used this , actually the external url that i am using is live site url. and if i have used window.location = "/Android"; than its redirecting to me the http://www.example.com/Android

Comment: my app is on my local system and external url is live website.