# Redirect to Android App from browser - before publishing app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-deep-link

I followed the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643272/redirect-to-android-app-from-a-website) on how to get a browser-to-app redirect working, but seemingly no matter what I do, I'm directed to the play store app with an "Item not found."-screen.

I have tried installing the app on the development tablet I'm working with, in the hopes that when I launch the debug app, go to a website and forget about the debug app, I'm directed back to the installed app.

The reason I want to be able to redirect to the app before publishing, is so that I can ensure that the Multi Factor Authentication feature, which uses a separate website via the browser, works as intended. The MFA feature is in part the whole reason for the apps existence in the first place, as it is very much a demonstration of said MFA system.

Is what I'm trying even possible?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.appname">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="customscheme"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Attempted redirect back to the app is:

```
intent:#Intent;scheme=customscheme;package=company.appname;end
```

I also noticed a log in logcat:

```
2019-11-20 10:57:55.828 25127-25233/? E/Volley: [692] bln.a: Unexpected response code 404 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=company.appname&nocache_irl=true
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With this configuration:

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
 <data
   android:host="my.app.com"
   android:path="launch"
   android:scheme="http">
 </data>
</intent-filter>
```

Whenever you hit **http://my.app.com/launch**, the system will prompt the user if they want to open with the app or with the browser.

For more information about intents, read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
What do you suggest putting in host?
What do you want to do with the package name?
It doesn't seem like putting the package name in the host field solves the issue.

Comment: <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

    <data
        android:host="www.my.app.com"
        android:path="launch"
        android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
Please refer the above intent-filter. So whenever you hit http://www.my.app.com/launch your app will be opened. You can change these values as per your requirements.

Comment: In this scenario, what would you call in the browser to redirect to the app?

Comment: I ask because I'm not sure I understand where you're going with this, differently from the standard solution posted in the other thread.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @user392117. 
For anyone else who may come here, the answer is that you indeed cannot open an unpublished app with the intent-system (Unless you somehow override the play-store lookup) 
Until you publish, you can use the web-linking method as outlined in the answer.